# React routing when page rendering (timeout Route)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example I have link for category: novosibirsk/spetstekhnika and I have same for cart novosibirsk/test-33_2736. Their difference only with this symbole _ .

```
         <Route
              path={`/${cityAlias}/:alias/:fullAlias?/:maxAlias?`}
                 element={
                    <Suspense fallback={<Loader />} >
                      {!window.location.href.includes('_') ?
                          <Catalog />
                              :
                            <CartProduct getIdPage={setIdProductPage} />}
                            </Suspense>
                       }></Route>
```

This work with default href, but with Navlink it will be on same page. Can I rerender Route when page loading or imitate reloading?

Answer (score 0):

You can use useLocation.

```
    const location = useLocation();

   <Route
     key={location} // Set the key to force re-render when it changes
     path={`/${cityAlias}/:alias/:fullAlias?/:maxAlias?`}
          element={
             <Suspense fallback={<Loader />} >
                {!window.location.href.includes('_') ? <Catalog /> 
                : <CartProduct getIdPage={setIdProductPage} />}
              </Suspense>
    }></Route>
```